# Field type is less accessible than field

Tags: c#, func, anonymous-delegates

I have the following declarations:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static Func<T1,T2, string> myFunc = (t1, t2) =>
    {
        var result = string.Empty
        //do some things with params t1 and t2, and build a string
        return result
    };
}
```

and I am consuming it like this:

```
var myString = Helper.myFunc(t1, t2);
```

in a different class. 
It does not compile, it says "Inconsistent accesibility: field type ... is less accessible than field Helper.myFunc"
I understand that it has to do with the anonymus declaration, but how can it be solved?

Comment: It currently doesn't compile on `T1, T2` not recognized. Please supply code sample that can help reproduce the problem. Please show the scope of the function + class in which you consume the function also

Comment: You must post a [mcve], it complains about a field but there is no trace of a field in your code, hence nobody here can tell you anything other than that the error message is usually correct.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify. T1 and T2 are valid types, it doesn't really matter what. And myFunc is the field, what do you mean there is no field?

Comment: T1,T2 may not be `public`

Comment: @GauravKP: awesome, one of the classes was internal, thank you.

Comment: @GauravKP Nailed it, T1 and T2 aren't open generic types in this context, they're actual types, which means somewhere there is a type T1 or T2 defined as not public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that T1 and T2 also accessible in this code

```
var myString = Helper.myFunc(t1, t2);
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thank you, T1 was made internal.